# Unable to get my Menu button to show on click (Inline JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Something is not right with my code as I can see my "navlinks" showing as text in my code.

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "0";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}
```

```css
.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f44336;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
```

Comment: Missed the JS code ```<script>

          var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
            function showMenu(){
                navLinks.style.right = "0";
            }
            function hideMenu(){
                navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
            }
        </script>```

Comment: use the edit option to add more to your question not the comments. Also SO has a build in Code-Snippet which you can sue by pressing `Ctrl + M` or the `<>`-Button

Comment: I just edited his/her OP for him

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ": can see my "navlinks" showing as text in my code.". Perhaps a screenshot would help.

Comment: @adsy when you edit questions then also move the code to a snippet and correct obvious spelling and grammar mistakes. Otherwise it is no real improvement.

Comment: There's nothing in your question HTML _to_ show at the moment.

Comment: @tocoshy, before part of his code was just inlined completely as normal text so it was an improvement.

Comment: @adsy you might see it as an improvement but improving it insufficiently when you clearly can do better is still insufficient. The guidelines for that within the review queue call that `no improvement`

Comment: Ok fair, I didn't realize that was in the guidelines. I will change my approach in future.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Do you want to toggle the navbar in/out when you click its button?

Comment: That is correct Andy, but I can see from JS script that something is not right, the navlinks after the variable is not detected as a class id but rather a white text

Comment: Can you post all the HTML associated with this issue? You're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the sidebar to slide in/out when the button is clicked. You can attach a listener to the button, and then use the [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method on [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to achieve this.

Note, I've switched your `div` for the more semantically correct `nav`, and use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) to style the layout.

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  nav.classList.toggle('show');
  if (nav.classList.contains('show')) {
    button.textContent = '<';
  } else {
    button.textContent = '>';
  }
}
```

```css
nav { display: flex; width: 100%; position: absolute; background: #efefef; top: 0; left: -172px; height: 100vh; width: 200px; transition: 0.5s; }
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 85%; padding: 0.5em; }
button { align-self: flex-start; width: 25px; height: 25px; width: 15%; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.show { left: 0px; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <button>></button>
</nav>
```